# dashes showing up on page, but can't find them in code

Tags: html

I'm have a question about my site specifically.
These dashes seem to be appearing in between each roll over image.  I've looked over the whole code (its pretty simple), and I can't seem to figure out where it is in the code and/or how to get rid of it.
Here's my site:
http://andiamlisa.com/

any help would be great - thanks

Comment: what do you exactly mean by "dashes".I find everything good in your site.

Comment: at the top in between portfolio and etsy, and in between etsy and blog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your CSS
    #navigation a {text-decoration: none;}

It looks like there is some hidden spacing between elements on Navigation Anchors.